React bootstrap typeahead multiple select not showing inline
React bootstrap typeahead multiple select not showing inline instead it breaks each select into next line, anyone faced this issue? please help.
I currently use version 5.2.2, I also tried version 6.2.xx but didn't work

it should instead show like this:


It looks like you're not including the package CSS:
// Import as a module in your JS
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';

// Be sure to also include the dedicated stylesheet if using Bootstrap 5
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.bs5.css';

Alternatively, if you're linking to the stylesheet from your HTML:
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css"
/>

See the docs for more.

Thank you very much,  I imported Typeahead.css in module and solved my problem. I want to buy you a coffee, let me know how can I do that. thanks
